# Why NullReferenceException for selecting checkbox present in listbox by button click event?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

```
 void y_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox che = lbox.SelectedItem as CheckBox;

        if ((bool)che.IsChecked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(che.Content.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here the button name is y and lbox is the listbox where I have added checkboxes dynamically.The button y is also added through Dynamically to the listbox.

For button click event in the above code it says `NullReferenceException` and lbox.SelectedItem is Null as seen by breakpoint..If I implement the same code in lboxSelectionChanged event it works fine and lbox.SelectedItem is not null..

What is wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Do you have a selection there?

Comment: ya..I selected the checkbox and then clicked the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing actually is IsChecked is different from selectionchanged event of listbox.The checking of a checkbox doesn't mean that a listbox selection has been made.
And the thing I found is that whenever I click on a checkbox content, the selection is changed but not when the checkbox is checked.
So, that's the thing.

Answer (score 3):

If the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) fails to cast to your desired type, it returns `null`.  Most likely what is happening here is that your `lbox.SelectedItem` is not a `CheckBox`, or it is `null`.  You should check that `che` is null before attempting to get its `IsChecked` property.

```
void y_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox che = lbox.SelectedItem as CheckBox;

    if (che == null) return;    // <--- Add this

    if ((bool)che.IsChecked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(che.Content.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Indish I don't know, that is for you to debug and figure out. Set breakpoints and step through the code. The debugger is your best friend.